# Lock a TTS method in Xamarin

Tags: multithreading, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, text-to-speech

I'm programming an application in Xamarin. And I'm using Azure's TTS service. I have 2 different methods. Both methods use TTS. But I don't want one to use it before the other one is done. How can I do this?

This is Main Mage:

```
namespace PorjectB1.Controller
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer m1Timer;
        private System.Timers.Timer m2Timer;
        static Model.TextToSpeech ttsService = new Model.TextToSpeech();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m1Timer= new System.Timers.Timer(15000);
            m1Timer.Elapsed += OnM1TimerElapsed;
            m1Timer.AutoReset = true;
            m1Timer.Enabled = true;
            m2Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
            m2Timer.Elapsed += OnM2Elapsed;
            m2Timer.AutoReset = true;
            m2Timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void OnM1TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            M1(this);
        }
        private void OnM2Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            M2(this);
        }

        private async void M1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string SpeechText=string.Empty;
             //Do Something...
             Speak(SpeechText); 
        }

        private async void M2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SpeechText=string.Empty;
             //Do Something...
             Speak(SpeechText);  
        }

        private void Speak(string text)
        {
             ttsService.Speak(text);
        }
    }
}
```

And This is TTS Service Class:

```
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

namespace PorjectB1.Model
{
    public class TextToSpeech
    {
        static private string speechKey { get; set; }
        static private string speechRegion { get; set; }
        
        public TextToSpeech()
        {
            speechKey = "***";
            speechRegion = "***";
        }

        static void OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(SpeechSynthesisResult speechSynthesisResult, string text)
        {
            switch (speechSynthesisResult.Reason)
            {
                case ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
                    //Log Something
                    break;
                case ResultReason.Canceled:
                    //Log Something
                    break;
                default:
                    //Log Something
                    break;
            }
        }

        public async void Speak(string text)
        {
            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion);

            using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig))
            {
                var speechSynthesisResult = await speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
                OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(speechSynthesisResult, text);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I tried Lock,Monitor and SemaphorSlim on Main Page Speak method to solve this.